# CSS Flex: flex items stretch vertically and text centered

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox

I have a question related to CSS flex, i'm a web dev but not CSS expert and i need your help on this CSS flex issue.

Here is the plnkr code snippet, you can see what i wanted here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5813XQb8qe2Niqjs7wch?p=preview)

```
  .flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .flex-item {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    padding: 10px;
    align-self: stretch;
  }
```

I want that:

- All flex items should be stretch.
- Flex item on the left should be both vertically and horizontally centered of the box.
- Flex item on the right should be vertically: center, horizontally: left.

Thanks in advance, appreciate all your helps :)

Comment: flex and flexbox are two different tags, i have edited the tag flex to flexbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your `<a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/JdsXLwJeOQirmjJhulFa?p=preview">Plunker[1]</a>` [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JdsXLwJeOQirmjJhulFa?p=preview). Please review and let me know is this what you need.

I have added flex-container to the orange div, so that the height will be height of the container

Comment: Thanks for your help, pretty close but the A+ should be in center both vertically and horizontally. I'm stuck at this stage. Thanks!

Comment: Please find the updated <a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/oxdRVsM2pHZUW1wfrGdc?p=preview">Plunker[2]</a>